# Replace NA values in a dataframe -- in place -- from a different data frame based on two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, purrr

I've got a df like:

```
df_o <- data.frame(code=c("Ex","Gd","TA", "TA","Fa","Po","Zz","Q"),
               val1=c(5,9,NA,NA,4,2,NA,NA),
               val2=c(1,5,NA,NA,5,6,NA,NA),
               id = c("X","Y","Z","Z","Q","X","Y","pP"),
               iz = c("X1","Y33","yz","zZ","3Q","zX","3Y","zpP"),
               stringsAsFactors = F)

  code val1 val2 id  iz
1   Ex    5    1  X  X1
2   Gd    9    5  Y Y33
3   TA   NA   NA  Z  yz
4   TA   NA   NA  Z  zZ
5   Fa    4    5  Q  3Q
6   Po    2    6  X  zX
7   Zz   NA   NA  Y  3Y
8    Q   NA   NA pP zpP
```

And a lookup df like:

```
df_miss <- data.frame(code = c("TA", "Zz"),
                      id = c("Z", "Y"),
                      val1 = c(17, 53), 
                      val2 = c(11, 12),
                      stringsAsFactors = F)

df_miss 

  code id val1 val2
1   TA  Z   17   11
2   Zz  Y   53   12
```

I would like to replace all the `NA`s in `df_o` such that the result looks like this:

```
data.frame(code=c("Ex","Gd","TA", "TA","Fa","Po","Zz","Q"),
                   val1=c(5,9,17,17,4,2,53,NA),
                   val2=c(1,5,53,53,5,6,12,NA),
                   id = c("X","Y","Z","Z","Q","X","Y","pP"),
                   iz = c("X1","Y33","yz","zZ","3Q","zX","3Y","zpP"),
           stringsAsFactors = F)

  code val1 val2 id  iz
1   Ex    5    1  X  X1
2   Gd    9    5  Y Y33
3   TA   17   53  Z  yz
4   TA   17   53  Z  zZ
5   Fa    4    5  Q  3Q
6   Po    2    6  X  zX
7   Zz   53   12  Y  3Y
8    Q   NA   NA pP zpP
```

Note that the lookup I'm doing between `df_o` and `df_miss` is based on a combination of two different columns: `code` & `id`.  Also note that if no match is found, then columns `val1` and `val2` remain as `NA`.  Finally, while each `code` and `id` have unique values for `val1` and `val2` the structure of `df_o` is such that there are duplicates among these fields.

I could do this operation with a merge and then drop the duplicated columns but I was hoping there's a cleaner, faster way. I was thinking that `purrr` might work here but I'm not sure how.

My actual data frame has 200K+ rows.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility involving `dplyr` and `tidyr` could be:

```
bind_rows(df_o, df_miss) %>%
 group_by(code, id) %>%
 fill(starts_with("val"), .direction = "up") %>%
 filter(!is.na(iz))

  code   val1  val2 id    iz   
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1 Ex        5     1 X     X1   
2 Fa        4     5 Q     3Q   
3 Gd        9     5 Y     Y33  
4 Po        2     6 X     zX   
5 Q        NA    NA pP    zpP  
6 TA       17    11 Z     yz   
7 TA       17    11 Z     zZ   
8 Zz       53    12 Y     3Y
```

Or with just `dplyr`:

```
bind_rows(df_o, df_miss) %>%
 arrange(code, id, val1, val2) %>%
 group_by(code, id) %>%
 mutate_at(vars(starts_with("val")), ~ first(.)) %>%
 filter(!is.na(iz))

  code   val1  val2 id    iz   
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1 Ex        5     1 X     X1   
2 Fa        4     5 Q     3Q   
3 Gd        9     5 Y     Y33  
4 Po        2     6 X     zX   
5 Q        NA    NA pP    zpP  
6 TA       17    11 Z     yz   
7 TA       17    11 Z     zZ   
8 Zz       53    12 Y     3Y
```

Comment: Would this work if the column counts are different between the dfs?  I just updated the problem statement just in case... and it does! Thank you!.

Comment: If the `code` and `id` row values are not necessarily unique there's a bit of a problem, tho.

Comment: I do not know your real data structure, so unless you post some sample data that really reflects your real data, I won't be able to give a correct answer.

Comment: Updated again - I'm pretty sure it covers all the idiosyncrasies now.